# How to detect carry and overflow?

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

Let's say that

0011 + 0111 = 1010

How to detect whether the operation generate carry and overflow?

Comment: What do you mean by carry and overflow? There are several ways of defining those. You need to be more precise.

Comment: You might be interested in the arithmetic flags set by CPUs and machine level instructions that access or depend on those flags.  However that is more of a programming topic than a mathematical (even though it needs to be consistent to be useful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can distinguish three carry-related functions per bit position:

**Generate**:
Carry for the bit position is set regardless of the next lower carry-in

**Propagate**:
Carry-in is forwarded to carry-out

**Kill**:
Carry-out is $0$ regardless of carry-in

If you are asking for *overflow*, you basically talk about the carry-out of the most-significant bit (*MSB*) position. If this *MSB* carry-out is $1$, the bitlength of the input operands is exceeded.

A description copied from [lecture slides](http://www.cerc.utexas.edu/~jaa/vlsi/lectures/8-1.pdf):

[image]